# Handwritten Digit Recognition using easyocr API

Tags: python, numpy

Ok I'm working in a project where i just want to extract digits from picture. Picture also contain alphabets. I'm using easyocr api but can't make logic to overcome this. Plz if you any link which helps me do share. [That's how i getting output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8kte.png)

Comment: Screenshots of code can not be accepted on Stack Overflow. Post your code as text!

Answer (score 1):

If the thing you are trying to read is only digits, you can limit your OCR search with the `allowlist` arg, which might improve your results.
Try this:

```
reader.readtext(IMAGE_PATH, allowlist ='0123456789')
```

If the thing you are trying to read contains alphabet characters but you want to ignore them, then you can just filter them out:

```
numeric_filter = filter(str.isdigit, my_text)
my_text = "".join(numeric_filter)
```

(If you want to keep decimals you can add an extra condition to the filter.)

Once filtered, you can typecast the result into an integer, assuming that is what you want to do:

```
result_number = int(my_text)
```

Comment: Thankyou very much but i have another problem now. If an image containing word SIX, ocr recognizing as 5. I can't fix it

Comment: @Muhammad Huzaifa That is expected behavior, `S` and `5` look very similar. You could check if the surrounding characters appear to be letters and selectively ignore digit matches in words, or you could just chalk it up to a false positive and move on. No OCR will have a 100% accuracy rate, and squiggles that look like numbers are likely to get detected as a number.